# How to convert a 'JSON styled' string to Json Object

Tags: c#, json, string, visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

I have a string in the style of JSon as shown below:

```
string msg = "{\"START\":\"19/08/2014\", \"END\":\"19/08/2014\", \"TIME\":\"11:39\",\"COUNT\":6}";
```

How/what is the best practise to convert this to an actual Json object, in which can be edited as such?

Furthermore, would I be able to send this through a serial port AS a JSon object, or would I have to convert it to JSon on the other side?

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid way to define a C# string.

Comment: Sorry, added escape chars etc. Was just using as example.

Comment: Also ; there are multiple ways to define a "json object" in languages other than Javascript. There are libraries (like https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) that are built to handle json in .NET.
When you transmit data via a serial connection, it mostly boils down to sending and retreiving strings, so either way, you'd have to reassemble it as a valid JSON object on the other side.

Comment: (that's still not a valid way to define a C# string btw :P)

Comment: I wish I could have just posted my code now @Timothy, but because I'm using a VM with no internet for development, I can't :(

Comment: @jbutler483 use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), this sort of thing is *very* trivial.

Comment: @James, i'm using NetMF?

Comment: @TimothyGroote - Due to my project **PM>** will not work, and so any nuget packages can't be used on **this** side. (i'm sending from a FEZ Panda to Bluetooth device).

Comment: @jbutler483 ah, just noticed that. What about [Json.NetMF](https://github.com/mweimer/Json.NetMF) then?

Comment: Timothy serial connectkon is not sending byte[]?

Answer (score -1):

Lots of libraries are available to convert a `Json` string into a `JSon object`. One of the mostly used library is `Newtonsoft.Json`. You can install it through `Package Manager console` of Visual Studio using below command

`PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Also whenever you want to transfer some complex data, `Serialize` and `Deserialize` at other end.
`JsonConvert class` provides a couple of methods to Serialize your data. eg:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestContent)
```

Same way you can `Deserialize` your Json string into a Json object like below

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOutputType>(responseContent)
```

Comment: Due to my project **PM>** will not work, and so any nuget packages can't be used on **this** side. (i'm sending from a FEZ Panda to Bluetooth device).

Comment: you will get Newtonsoft.Json dlls from web

Comment: Bluetooth device? Why you dont deploy the device with the json newton dll?